# Error compiling header file with a map of type map<string,struct>

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble compiling a class that has a map. I define, in the private, the struct and then I declare de map. The thing is that the compiler g++  gives me error in the functions where I use iterators to that map, since it seems that g++ doesn't recognise the struct.

.hh file:

```
#ifndef _X_HH_
#define _X_HH_
class X{
public:
(lots of function and procedure headers)

private:
struct something{
(Its attributes)
};
map<string,something> mymap;
};
#endif
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Make a public type alias? http://ideone.com/1GwQsX

Comment: Forgot to `#include <map>` and `std::`?. Looks like more includes are missing.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>

class X{
public:
    //
    
private:
    struct something{
        int a;
    };

    std::map<std::string,something> m_mymap;
};

int main(){
    X xx;
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation please. What is this code doing?

Comment: This code is the .hh file of a class that has in its attributes a struct that contains two different int values and a map<string,another_class>, and a map<string,the_previous struct>. The thing is that I don't know if I have to declare the struct in the private or in the public of the .hh file, since I get compilation error when trying to compile the .cc file of that class. The compiler doesn't recognise the struct when it arrives to the headers of the functions of the class in the .cc file.